# How to mute output in apple aurio Touch (audio sessioin example) application?

Tags: iphone, session, audio, toolbox

I have wrote detector of breath  based on apple's [aurio Touch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Listings/Classes_aurioTouchAppDelegate_mm.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007770-Classes_aurioTouchAppDelegate_mm-DontLinkElementID_6)
example application. But i can not figure how to set audio unit or audio 
session not to play sounds from audio input. Now when blowing in the mic, 
i can hear the breath from iphone speaker. How to prevent this?

Here is apple's audio session init code:

```
            XThrowIfError(AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, rioInterruptionListener, self), "couldn't initialize audio session");
        XThrowIfError(AudioSessionSetActive(true), "couldn't set audio session active\n");


        UInt32 audioCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_RecordAudio;
        XThrowIfError(AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(audioCategory), &audioCategory), "couldn't set audio category");
        XThrowIfError(AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange, propListener, self), "couldn't set property listener");

        Float32 preferredBufferSize = .005;
        XThrowIfError(AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareIOBufferDuration, sizeof(preferredBufferSize), &preferredBufferSize), "couldn't set i/o buffer duration");

        UInt32 size = sizeof(hwSampleRate);
        XThrowIfError(AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareSampleRate, &size, &hwSampleRate), "couldn't get hw sample rate");

        XThrowIfError(SetupRemoteIO(rioUnit, inputProc, thruFormat), "couldn't setup remote i/o unit");

        dcFilter = new DCRejectionFilter[thruFormat.NumberChannels()];

        UInt32 maxFPS;
        size = sizeof(maxFPS);
        XThrowIfError(AudioUnitGetProperty(rioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &maxFPS, &size), "couldn't get the remote I/O unit's max frames per slice");

        fftBufferManager = new FFTBufferManager(maxFPS);
        l_fftData = new int32_t[maxFPS/2];



        XThrowIfError(AudioOutputUnitStart(rioUnit), "couldn't start remote i/o unit");

        size = sizeof(thruFormat);
        XThrowIfError(AudioUnitGetProperty(rioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &thruFormat, &size), "couldn't get the remote I/O unit's output client format");
```

Comment: @DesperateLearner checkout my own answer. Works for me.

Comment: So I assume u called the:   void SilenceData(AudioBufferList *inData)
{
 for (UInt32 i=0; i < inData->mNumberBuffers; i++)
  memset(inData->mBuffers[i].mData, 0, inData->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize);
   
}

Comment: One more thing. Is it possible to measure the speed of wind using the Aurio touch concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many Thanks to [Tim Bolstad](http://timbolstad.com/)
His answer:
AURIOTouch uses a single callback to pass audio from input to output. So the simplest thing would be to zero
out the ioData structure after you've done your breath detection.

Something like:

```
for (UInt32 i=0; i < inData->mNumberBuffers; i++)
memset(inData->mBuffers[i].mData, 0, inData->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize);
```

Or you could look at the CAPlayThrough example, which has separate callbacks for input and output.